# Canvas partial text drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I need to draw text on 2 consecutive bitmaps that form a single continues bitmap.

- The text can begin on the first bitmap and end on the second bitmap.
- A letter can begin on the first bitmap but end on the second bitmap.

[image]

I can draw the text in full twice using a negative offset on the second bitmap

```
//first bitmap
canvas1.drawText(text, position, top, paint);

//second bitmap
canvas2.drawText(text, -lengthOfTextOnFirstBitmap, top, paint);
```

Seems like the wrong way to address the issue, I would like to support **n** bitmaps and I'm looking for a better solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you just have one textfield and several bitmaps arranged behind it?

Comment: @SergChernata no, this is not a TextView issue, I have to do custom printing using a canvas.

Comment: did you try this example code on github https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable ??

Comment: @Javacoder doesnt seem to be related to the issue described at the question

Comment: @aviran i think you are not understand your requirment....

Comment: i understand your requirment...!!

Comment: so you are calling `canvas.drawBitmap(b0, ....)` then `canvas.drawBitmap(b1, ...)`, right? so simply call `canvas.drawText(...)` after drawing those `Bitmap`s

Comment: No, I have 2 different canvas objects, each contains a part of the complete bitmap data. when I perform drawText() I do it directly on a bitmap (using a canvas wrap)

Comment: what 2 canvas objects? what do you mean? how many views do you have? are they custom ones?

Comment: @pskink if you want to draw on bitmap you wrap it in Canvas. Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(...); then you can paint over it. So I have 2 canvases with underlying bitmaps.

Comment: Im spliting the canvas to bypass android's memory limitations on bitmap sizes, but that is besides the point. What I need is a way to partialy print text on bitmaps, without having to reprint the whole text twice and compensate using position offsets.

Comment: i have no idea what you really want and why you cannot draw those two bitmaps and the text over them

Comment: It's impossible to create a single bitmap in the size I need, Android limits you to 2000px width. So I'm using more than one bitmap to hold the entire bitmap data (which is much larger than 2000px width)

Comment: ok so you have for example 100 mini bitmaps 200x200 instead of one 2000x2000, then you draw all of them (or maybe just a subset) using `Canvas#drawBitmap` and finally calling `Canvas#drawText` to draw your text over them, whats the point in calling `drawText` many times?

Comment: the text length in pixels might need to span over several tiles (mini bitmaps), drawing it on the first tile (which can only contain a part of the text), will not reflect in the pixels in the adjacent tile - I need to draw the rest of text on the next tile manually. Splitting into characters is not applicable since clean cuts between letters are not guaranteed.

Comment: i got it now (i hope), so you want the text on those mini bitmaps, right? but why? after all you will use them to draw on a larger canvas by calling canvas.drawBitmap(miniBitmap00, ...); canvas.drawBitmap(miniBitmap01, ...); etc so draw them in a "background layer" and your text in the "foreground layer" or you have some api where you can use only bitmaps (and thats why the text need to be on those mini bitmaps)?

Comment: Thats not the case, I cant layer the text for various technical reasons.

Comment: so you have to draw it twice, if you have N bitmaps the small optimization would be to use `Paint#getTextBounds` for quick checking which mini bitmaps to draw on and which to skip

Answer (score 1):

Just translate the canvas so that you draw in the same "place", but the canvas is positioned just to the right of the first canvas.  This should make a pixel-perfect text rendering.

```
//first bitmap
canvas1.drawText(text, position, top, paint);

//second bitmap
canvas2.translate(width_of_1st_bitmap, 0);
canvas2.drawText(text, position, top, paint);
canvas2.translate(-width_of_1st_bitmap, 0);
```

Comment: It's a different approach to using offsets, still requires full draws of the text for every bitmap, and does not solve my optimization problem for n bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. You can't use `drawText` to partially draw in one Bitmap and then in another bitmap. `drawText` is a single atomic method call that can be performed on a single instance of `Canvas`. And you can't switch bitmaps of the canvas in the middle of a `drawText` call.

But there are alternatives. If you are going to have `Bitmap1` and `Bitmap2` in the memory at the same time, and you are not looking for any layering effects (xFermode drawing) then you could just simply use a single Bitmap and then get two bitmaps out of them.

But if you are going to draw in 2 bitmaps to avoid OutOfMemory error, then you can do something as below.

1. There is no need for 2 canvas objects. Just have one canvas and use `setBitmap()` to switch bitmaps.
2. Any draw operation in `Canvas` is atomic. So instead of using a single `drawText(text)` you will need to split the `text` into two and then draw one in the first bitmap and the other in the second. You can use `Paint.getTextBounds()` or `Paint.measureText()` to know how to split the `text`. But this is really messy and you need to calculate a lot of stuff.
3. `drawText` is a very fast call. It won't take much time even if you call it with a large text for 10 times. So I don't really think you need all this optimizations at all. However if you going to use 'drawText' and then 'drawCircle' and then 'drawRect' (multiple draw calls), then you can record these calls in [Picture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html). And then you can playback this Picture on the Canvas by switching the bitmaps. This will reduce the method overhead time.